# Is there a way to trace errors in XCode? Errors when using a Cordova plugin in my Ionic/Capacitor project

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am having some issues when trying to run my Ionic/Capacitor app in XCode. The app is using a Cordova plugin and I believe it is what is causing the errors to be thrown.

The errors are appearing in `CapacitorBridge.swift` and `WebViewDelegationHandler.swift`.

Are there ways to trace which plugins or packages may be causing the issue?

Here is my `ionic info`:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 6.12.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 7.0.12

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 5.0.5
   @capacitor/core : 5.0.5

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.14.0
   native-run                             : 1.7.2

System:

   NodeJS : v16.20.0 (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.19.4
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

Screen shot of errors:

[image]

I did some searching and didn't see anything else posted with these issues, so any thoughts or additional direction would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Could you post `CapacitorBridge.swift` source code? Have you tried recreating ios platform? Xcode version?

Comment: @WoAiNii - it looks like this is from the Pods in the project. I see the issue in `Pods > Development Pods > Capacitor > CapacitorBridge.swift > registerPluginInstance`.

Comment: It appears this is an issue with my older version of Xcode (12) and trying to use Capacitor 5, which requires Xcode 14+.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is an issue with older versions of Xcode (12) and trying to use Capacitor 5, which requires Xcode 14+.